# Assembler в Pascal и в C#

Tags: c#, ассемблер, pascal

Есть программа на паскале, написанная изначально не мной.
Перевожу ее на C#. В одной из части программы идет весьма своеобразный расчет контрольной суммы файлов. Контрольная сумма хранится в базе в формате `bigint` и функция расчета контрольной суммы выглядит так:

```
function GetCheckSum(FileName: string): DWORD;
var
  F: file of DWORD;
  P: Pointer;
  Fsize: DWORD;
  Buffer: array[0..500] of DWORD;
begin
  FileMode := 0;
  AssignFile(F, FileName);
  Reset(F);
  Seek(F, FileSize(F) div 2);
  Fsize := FileSize(F) - 1 - FilePos(F);
  if Fsize > 500 then
    Fsize := 500;
  BlockRead(F, Buffer, Fsize);
  Close(F);
  P := @Buffer;
  asm
        XOR     eax, eax
        XOR     ecx, ecx
        mov     edi, P

    @again:
        add     eax, [edi + 4 * ecx]
        inc     ecx
        cmp     ecx, Fsize
        jl      @again
        mov     @result, eax
  end;
end;
```

Подскажите, что происходит в Ассемблере и как бы могла выглядеть данная конструкция в C#?

Воспользовался следующим:

```
private long GetCheckSum(string FilePath)
{
    byte[] FBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
    int FSize = FBytes.Length / 2;
    int FToRead = FSize + 500 > FBytes.Length ? FBytes.Length : FSize + 500;
    long FSum = 0;
    for (int i = FSize; i < FToRead; i++)
    {
        FSum += FBytes[i];
    }
    return FSum;
}
```

На мой взгляд получилось идентично. Поправьте, если я не прав.

Comment: Получилось не идентично, т.к. в оригинале размер элемента буфера - 4 байта (`DWORD` - 32-битное беззнаковое целое), а у вас `FBytes` - массив байт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал так:

```
private long GetCheckSum(string FilePath)
{
    byte[] FBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
    int FSize = FBytes.Length / 2;
    int FToRead = FSize + 500 * 4 > FBytes.Length ? FBytes.Length : FSize + 500 * 4;
    long FSum = 0;
    for (int i = FSize; i < FToRead; i += 4)
    {
        FSum += BitConverter.ToUInt32(FBytes, i);
    }
    return FSum;
}
```

Вроде как, возвращает то, что надо. `BitConverter.ToUInt32` конвертирует 4 байта в массиве с указанной позиции в 32-битное беззнаковое число. Сама функция `GetCheckSum` читает последовательность байтов из файла. Узнает где середина файла и начиная с нее перебегает через максимум 2000 элементов (если столько есть) с шагом 4. То есть по факту максимум 500 шагов. С помощью функции `BitConverter.ToUInt32` получает сумму беззнаковых чисел и возвращает ее.

Answer (score 4):

Просто сумма 32-разрядных беззнаковых чисел (по модулю 2^32, если возникнет переполнение).

```
UInt32 buffer[500];    
sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < fsize; i++)
  sum += buffer[i];
```

Файл читается как бинарный, суммирование осуществляется для чисел из **второй половины файла** (благодаря `Seek`), их количество не превышает 500. Т.о. для размера файла 8000 байт (2000 чисел) прочитаны будут числа с номерами от 1000 по 1499. Для размера файла 800 байт (200 чисел) прочитаны будут числа с номерами от 100 по 199.

Comment: если я правильно понял, в самой функции: считываются не более первых 500 строк файла. Только я так и не понял, что со всем этим происходит в коде ассемблера. Что происходит с каждой обрабатываемой строкой файла? Считались строки в буфер. И пошел буфер по циклу. А шаг цикла так и остается загадкой.

Comment: Я привёл примерный эквивалент. Шаг цикла обусловлен размером DWORD - 4 байта. Строки не используются, какая именно часть файла читается - я уже сказал, сейчас добавил примеры.

Comment: Только я бы на всякий случай явно прописал блок `unchecked`.

Comment: @Rekssel, точно не строк. Скорее всего int'ов. Кстати, в ответе про чтение файла ничего нет...

Answer (score 2):

Пояснения на c-подобном псевдокоде

```
    XOR     eax, eax // DWORD eax = 0; // здесь будет храниться результат
    XOR     ecx, ecx // int ecx = 0; // будет работать как индекс
    mov     edi, P // DWORD * edi = buffer;

 @again:
    add     eax, [edi + 4 * ecx] // eax += edi[ecx]; // На ассемблере *4 потому что размер элемента 4 байта
    inc     ecx // ecx++;
    // if(ecx<Fsize) goto again;
    cmp     ecx, Fsize  
    jl      @again
    mov     @result, eax // result = eax;
```